# cancellation ideals in Noetherian domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, projective-module

For an ideal $I$ in a commutative ring with unity $R$, let us say $I$ is a cancellation ideal if for ideals $J,K$, $IJ \cong IK \implies J \cong K$.

Now let $I$ be a cancellation ideal in a Noetherian domain $R$. Is it true that $I$ is projective as an $R$-module ?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I was trying to show that $I$ is invertible ... it would then imply that $I$ is projective ...

Comment: you can add your idea as an edit to your question.. Can you think of any other characterization of projective R modules over Noetherian rings?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I am not sure whether my idea of trying to show invertibility of ideal is a good idea or not

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: f.g. module over Noetherian ring is projective iff it is locally free iff it is flat ...